# Arbitrary precision integer on GPU

Tags: bigint, arbitrary-precision

I'm currently doing a primality test on huge numbers (up to 10M digits).

Right now, I'm using a c program using the GMP library. I did some parallelization using OpenMP and got a nice speedup (3.5~ with 4 cores). The problem is that I don't have enough CPU cores to make it feasible to run with my whole dataset.

I have an NVidia GPU and, I tried to find an alternative to GMP, but for GPUs. It can be either CUDA or OpenCL.

Is there an arbitrary precision library that I can run on my GPU? I'm also open to using another programming language if there is a simple or more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.

Comment: The problem itself (primarily tests) should be parallelizable? Then Cuda threads can do C or C++ instructions. You should optimize memory accesses (coalescing and/or using shared memory. Perhaps using the 32 threads of a warp for cooperating on one task and the other threads for higher-level parallelism. What operations would you need to test for primality? Multiplications? Would there be optimizations? FFT-like?

Answer (score 8):

It seems the [Julia Language](https://julialang.org/) is already able to do multiprecision arithmetic and use the GPU (see [here](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/multiprecision-arithmetic-in-cuda/18087) for a simple example combining these two), but you might have to learn Julia and rewrite your code.

The [CUMP](https://github.com/skystar0227/CUMP) library is meant to be a GMP substitute for CUDAs, it attempts to make it easier for porting GMP code to CUDAs by offering an interface similar to GMP, for example you replace `mpf_...` variables and functions by `cumpf_...` ones. There is a demo you can `make` if it fits your CUDA. No [documentation](https://www.jsst.jp/e/JSST2013/extended_abstract/pdf/Paper%2076.pdf) or support though, you'll have to go through the code to see if it works.

The [CAMPARY](https://homepages.laas.fr/mmjoldes/campary/) library from people in LAAS-CNRS might be a shot as well, but no documentation either. It has been applied in more [research](https://homepages.laas.fr/mmjoldes/) than CUMP, so some chance there. An [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55172701/outputting-values-from-campary) here gives some clarification on how to use it.

[GRNS](https://github.com/kisupov/grns) uses the residue number system on CUDA-compatible processors, it has no documentation but an interesting [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9043511) is available. Also, see this [one](https://thesai.org/Downloads/Volume11No9/Paper_1-Efficient_GPU_Implementation_of_Multiple_Precision.pdf).

[XMP](https://github.com/NVlabs/xmp) comes directly from NVIDIA labs, but seems incomplete and has no docs also. Some info [here](https://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6349-niall-emmart-xmp-library-internals.pdf) and a paper [here](http://www.acsel-lab.com/arithmetic/arith23/data/1616a047.pdf).

[XMP 2.0](https://github.com/NVlabs/CGBN) seems newer but only support sizes up to 32k bits for now.

[GPUMP](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5577902/) looks promising, but seems not available for download, perhaps by contacting the authors.

The [MPRES-BLAS](https://github.com/kisupov/mpres-blas) is a multiprecision library for linear algebra on CUDAs, and does - of course - [have](https://github.com/kisupov/mpres-blas/tree/master/src/arith) code for basic arithmetic. Also, papers [here](http://psta.psiras.ru/read/psta2020_3_61-84.pdf) and [here](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0743731519303302?via%3Dihub).

I haven't tested any of those, so please let us know if any of those work well.